apply specific filters on specific group of requests in spring
I have a spring boot app in which there are 2 types of requests based on role:
admin and user.
I have 2 different jwt service for each and therefore filters and configs as well.
Now. I want the adminFilter only to apply on the admin requests /api/admin/** and the userFilter on user requests /api/user/**
For each filterChain I added
.addFilterBefore(<corresponding filter>, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
The problem is that each requests goes through both filters, so I have to ignore every type of admin requests on the user side and the other way around. Inside the filter I check the request url and skip to the next filter if's not the right type,  so the authorization wont fail.
I believe there is a way more simple method for this.
AdminConfig:
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AdminSecurityConfig {

    private final AdminJwtAuthenticationFilter adminJwtAuthenticationFilter;
    @Qualifier("adminUserAuthenticationProvider")
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain adminSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                //.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("api/admin/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                //.and()

                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                        authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().exceptionHandling(httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer ->
                        httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(adminJwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer adminSecurityCustomizer() {

        return web -> web
                .ignoring()
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(POST, "/api/admin/testing/**"))
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(POST,"/api/admin/auth/**"))
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(GET,"/api/web/**"))
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(PUT,"/api/web/**"))
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(DELETE,"/api/web/**"))
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(POST,"/api/web/**"));
    }

AdminFilter:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
public class AdminJwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final AdminJwtService adminJwtService;
    private final AdminUserRepository adminUserRepository;
    RequestMatcher customFilterUrl = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/admin/**");


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        logger.info("Request: "+request.getRequestURI());
        if (customFilterUrl.matches(request)) {
            logger.info("Admin request");
            final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            final String jwt;
            final String userEmail;
            logger.info("Authentication started");
            logger.info(authHeader);
            if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                logger.info("No AuthHeader");
                return;
            }
            jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
            userEmail = adminJwtService.extractUserName(jwt);
            logger.info("admin: " + userEmail);
            if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.adminUserRepository.findOneByEmail(userEmail).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(""));
                if (adminJwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                    logger.info("Valid token");
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails,
                            null,
                            userDetails.getAuthorities()
                    );
                    authToken.setDetails(
                            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                    );
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                    logger.info("is authenticated: " + authToken.isAuthenticated());
                    request.getRequestDispatcher(((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath()).forward(request, response);
                    return;
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            logger.info("Not admin request");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

